# Pinning a Google Admob Banner to the bottom of an iPhone X

Tags: swift, autolayout, admob

I have a Google Admob banner (created in code) on the bottom of the main screen in an old project. It works perfect on all devices, except the iPhone X in the Xcode 9 Simulator. The banner is pinned to the absolute bottom of the screen, behind the Home "button" gesture area. I need it to be above that bottom safe area.

```
adBannerView.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.midX, y: view.bounds.height - adBannerView.bounds.height / 2)
```

How can I change the center point, so that the bottom of the banner is just above the Home gesture area?

For reference, here is a screenshot of what's occurring.
[image: Admob banner behind iPhone X home area]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set bottom constraint to admob banner using [safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide).

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: admobbanner, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 0.0)
}
```

Or with snapkit:

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    make.bottom.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.bottomMargin)
}
```

It will left the space = safeAreaLayoutGuide bottomMargin

Comment: Whenever I tried the `NSLayoutConstraint` it gives me the error: `terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` 

`Constraint items must each be an instance of UIView, or UILayoutGuide.`

Comment: @BrunoRecillas You should create new question and show the code, i'll take a look at it.

Comment: I have the exact same error - could you resolve it or post a link to an according question?

Comment: @Yeehaw I had the same error, you need to use the guide as the input and not the guide.bottomAnchor/others.. so the toItem should be: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

Comment: does anyone know why this is not working for facebook audience network ?